# how to pass a retried database data to another page?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysqli

I am trying to make a simple booking form.
1st showing available cities and packages in a page from database
when the user clicks on the `BOOK` button in the page, the page will redirect to the action page where the selected form/package should be added to the `booking` table automatically and send a confirmation mail.

The following code generates the available packages from the database:

`include 'inc/db_connect.php';`

//working connection to the DB

```
$sql="SELECT pkg, fcity, dcity, price, details FROM tour_package WHERE fcity='".$fcity_search."'  ORDER BY fcity ASC"; 
$sqlresult=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$afct=mysqli_affected_rows($con);
while($pkg=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlresult,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
    $num[]=$pkg['pkg'];
    $fcity[]=$pkg['fcity'];
    $dcity[]=$pkg['dcity'];
    $price[]=$pkg['price'];
    $details[]=$pkg['details'];
    $num++;
}

$i=0;
$book_btn_id = 1;
while($i < $afct)
{
    echo '<form action="book_tour_action.php">';
            $num_var_to_db = $num[$i];
        echo '<span class="search-class-row"><div class="search-results-label">Package : </div>'.$num[$i].'<br/></span>';
        echo '<span class="search-class-row"><div class="search-results-label">From : </div>'. $fcity[$i].'<br/></span>';
        echo '<span class="search-class-row"><div class="search-results-label">Destination : </div>' . $dcity[$i].'<br/></span>';
        echo '<span class="search-class-row"><div class="search-results-label">Price : </div>' .$price[$i].'<br/></span>';
        echo '<span class="search-class-row"><div class="search-results-label">Details :</div>' . $details[$i].'<br/></span>';
        //echo '<a href="#" class="booking-btn" name="bb'.$book_btn_id++.'"> BOOK </a>';
        echo '<input type="submit" value="BOOK" class="booking-btn" name="bb'.$book_btn_id++.'">';
        echo '<br><br/><hr/>';                          
        $i++;
    echo '</form>';
}
```

I've set a dynamic name to the `BOOK` button.

**book_tour_action.php:**

```
echo $num_var_to_db;
$sql = "INSERT INTO booking (num_var_to_db)
VALUES ('$num_var_to_db')";
```

But it says UNDEFINED VARIABLE when the `BOOK` button is clicked.

So that means the data is not passed to `book_tour_action.php` I guess.
How can I make it work?

Comment: use `mysqli_num_rows()` to check number of rows return  your SELECT query instead `mysqli_affected_rows()` and pass your query result not your connection into it

Comment: Plus i m not able to understand what you trying to do with `name="bb'.$book_btn_id++.'">';`

Comment: There is no `$BOOK` in your code so it seems strange that you'd get an undefined variable on that. Is there more to this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep `$num_var_to_db` value in hidden input field in the form to get the value. Try do like below :

```
  echo '<form action="book_tour_action.php">';
  $num_var_to_db = $num[$i];
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="num_var_to_db" value="'.$num_var_to_db.'">'
       echo '<span class="search-class-row"><div class="search-results-label">Package : </div>'.$num[$i].'<br/></span>';
      echo '<span class="search-class-row"><div class="search-results-label">From : </div>'. $fcity[$i].'<br/></span>';
   echo '<span class="search-class-row"><div class="search-results-label">Destination : </div>' . $dcity[$i].'<br/></span>';
      echo '<span class="search-class-row"><div class="search-results-label">Price : </div>' .$price[$i].'<br/></span>';
      echo '<span class="search-class-row"><div class="search-results-label">Details :</div>' . $details[$i].'<br/></span>';
     //echo '<a href="#" class="booking-btn" name="bb'.$book_btn_id++.'"> BOOK </a>';
     echo '<input type="submit" value="BOOK" class="booking-btn" name="bb'.$book_btn_id++.'">';
      echo '<br><br/><hr/>';                          
       $i++;
 echo '</form>';
```

and in the php page you can do following to get the value:

```
$num_var_to_db = $_REQUEST['num_var_to_db'];
```